# parsing complicated jsons with Aeson

Tags: json, haskell

I'm trying to parse a call to an API into a haskell record type using the Aeson Library

I'm using wikipedia pages, and parsing them to the title and a list of links.
A sample would be this,

```
{"query":{"pages":{"6278041":{"pageid":6278041,"ns":0,"title":"Lass","links":[{"ns":0,"title":"Acronym"},{"ns":0,"title":"Dead Like Me"},{"ns":0,"title":"Donna Lass"},{"ns":0,"title":"George Lass"},{"ns":0,"title":"Girl"},{"ns":0,"title":"Lassana Diarra"},{"ns":0,"title":"Lightning Lass"},{"ns":0,"title":"Real Madrid"},{"ns":0,"title":"Shadow Lass"},{"ns":0,"title":"Solway Lass"},{"ns":0,"title":"Szymon Lass"},{"ns":0,"title":"The Bonnie Lass o' Fyvie"},{"ns":0,"title":"The Tullaghmurray Lass"},{"ns":0,"title":"Woman"},{"ns":12,"title":"Help:Disambiguation"}]}}}}
```

and I would like to parse it to the title and a list of links in a data type like this.

```
data WikiPage = WikiPage { title :: String,
                           links :: String }
```

What code I currently have is this,

```
instance FromJSON WikiPage where
  parseJSON j = do
    o <- parseJSON j
    let id = head $ o .: "query" .: "pages" 
    let name = o .: "query" .: "pages" .: id .: "title"
    let links = mapM (.: "title") (o .: "query".: "pages" .: id .: "links")
    return $ WikiPage name links
```

I'm getting the error,

```
Couldn't match expected type `Data.Text.Internal.Text'
                with actual type `[Char]'
    In the second argument of `(.:)', namely `"title"'
```

I don't really get whats going on, I feel like there must be a problem with how I'm mapping over the links but I'm not sure exactly what has to be done. I also don't get how I'm supposed to use id in the second query string as it's a parser (I'm sure I need to use applicative in here somewhere but I'm not sure how.) I haven't found any examples that decompose more complicated jsons like this.

Comment: in addition to th e`OverloadedStrings` issue, those `let`s don't look right, e.g. you should replace `let name =` by `name <-`, since `name` is currently of type `Parser a` but you want `a`

Answer (score 14):

I'm also trying to figure out aeson. I had the same problem you were having, and I solved it by adding `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` at the top of my source file. I'm very new to Haskell, but I believe it adds an unofficial extension to the language, presumably to allow strings to double as other string-like datatypes.

Comment: That is correct. You can also use `Data.Text.pack` to manually convert a `String` to `Text`.

Comment: Had the same problem (with a different library, Campfire) and 'pack' solved for me.